# SSL doesn't work for PassBook on iPhones

Tags: asp.net, iphone, iis, ssl

We built a passbook server on ASP.NET and it worked perfect in Dev. environment (without SSL certificate).
Passes that were generated could be seen on iPhone (in dev. mode) and on Mac.

Then we bought an SSL from Thawte (just for the domain) and added the certificate to IIS.
Of course, domain name is associated with the same IP address.

So now, when a link to the pass is generated on our server, normal iPhone can't download it, saying "Can't download the file".
If I click the same link in Safari on Mac, it is opened, when click it from Chrome - file is downloaded.

We've tried whatever was possible - enabling SSL 2.0, then SSL 3.0 on the server. We also trued disabling all SSL and enabling all TLS instead - no luck.

The aspnet passbook server is configured using the following.
SSL 2 (disabled)
SSL 3 (disabled)
TLS 1.0 (enabled)
TLS 1.1 (enabled)
TLS 1.2 (enabled)

here is the ssl test result: http://clip2net.com/s/3lUpIiq
seems pretty configured correctly.

the pass can be viewed/run to any mac safari browsers, downloads pretty well on non-safari browsers, but not on iphones. 
it just says, cannot download the file. we have been trying to search the internet for possible answers but no luck.

the thing is that the browsers including mac safari recognizes well the certificate installed on the aspnet passbook server. but it seems iphones does not recognize the certificate.

Please advise what else could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: hi guys, anyone with answers? thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out what the error was, when we tried to debug it on a MAC with XCode. What it showed was the pass was missing some required fields, in our case, the icon/logo image, and second was the pass registration endpoint had some errors.

We tried to fix these issues including our pass registration endpoint. After that, all went well and has been working smoothly.

Depending on the pass type, there must be required fields that must be met, else, the pass won't install correctly on production mode.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the webServiceUrl have 'https'? If not, it needs to (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW3).

Other than that, you should be able to view the error from Passbook in the console window in XCode.